# AWS resources hide/disable for IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS and I am wondering if there is a way to disable or hide projects based on IAM users, Something like resource group restricted to some of the IAM users.
eg. Let say multiple users develop 2 apps on same AWS account but don't want to share the resources (apis, lambda functions, s3 buckets etc.). Each user will see the resources of his own project not the other. They all have access to these resources but need to block irrelevant project works.These user groups are working independently on private client projects so sharing is not an option.

If this is not possible is there any other way or solution to this matter.I don't wanna use two separate billing accounts in AWS.

Im not sure this is the correct place to ask this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to implement this through IAM.
You can use AWS Organizations service to manage multiple accounts, and pay billing for all member accounts through the same credit card.